# New line (\n) in substring does not work in Utilities.formatString

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am generating a google doc files through a `google-apps-script`. I see an interesting behavior by `Utilities.formatString` function.

```
var string = Utilities.formatString('apples \n oranges')
```

gives

```
apples
oranges
```

But if I feed the same line via substring,

```
var substring = 'apples \n oranges'
var string = Utilities.formatString('%s' , substring)
```

gives

```
apples \n oranges
```

Q: What's the fix?

Comment: Try: var substring = 'apples \\n oranges'

Comment: Try using double quotes `"` instead of single quote `'`. On a sidenote; I just tested this and your code seems to work just fine, doing exactly what you are expecting.